# Does a line intersect a polygon?

Tags: excel, computational-geometry, vba

I re-purposed sijipie's code here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/713005-does-point-fall-within-polygon-visual-basic-applications-function.html

What I need to do is to decide if a line is within a polygon.

Admittedly, this is a bit lazy as I don't test the intersection of the line with every single side, as I iterate the midpoints of the line and test them for being an interior point.

I was wondering if there's a faster way to do this.

VBA Code below:

```
Function PolyLineIntersect(lXY As Range, polyXY As Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, polySides As Integer
    Dim Result As Boolean
    Dim x As Double, y As Double
    Dim aXY As Variant
    Dim mXY(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Integer
    Dim tXY(1 To 5) As Boolean

    x = lXY.Cells.value2(1, 1)
    y = lXY.Cells.value2(1, 2)
    xb = lXY.Cells.value2(1, 3)
    yb = lXY.Cells.value2(1, 4)

    mXY(1, 1) = x
    mXY(1, 2) = y
    mXY(2, 1) = xb
    mXY(2, 2) = yb
    mXY(3, 1) = (xb + x) / 2
    mXY(3, 2) = (yb + y) / 2
    mXY(4, 1) = (xb + mx1) / 2
    mXY(4, 2) = (yb + my1) / 2
    mXY(5, 1) = (xb + mx1) / 2
    mXY(5, 2) = (yb + my1) / 2

    Result = False

    aXY = polyXY.Value

    polySides = polyXY.Rows.Count
    j = polySides - 1
    For a = 1 To 5                
      x = mXY(a, 1)
      y = mXY(a, 2)                
      For i = 1 To polySides                     
        If (((aXY(i, 2) < y And aXY(j, 2) >= y) _
         Or (aXY(j, 2) < y And aXY(i, 2) >= y)) _
         And (aXY(i, 1) <= x Or aXY(j, 1) <= x)) Then                  
          Result = Result Xor (aXY(i, 1) + (y - aXY(i, 2)) / (aXY(j, 2) - aXY(i, 2)) * (aXY(j, 1) - aXY(i, 1)) < x)                            
        End If
        j = i        
      Next i
    Next a
    PolyLineIntersect = Result

End Function
```

Comment: deleted mathematica tag. If you think it belongs you should say why.

Comment: Seems more appropriate for CodeReview than StackOverflow.

Comment: Duly noted. Was not aware of it. Thank you xidgel!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all polygon vertices lie in the same semi-plane (left or right) relative to the given line using [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). If yes, line does not intersect polygon.

```
Side = Sign(CrossProduct(L2-L1, P[i] - L1))
where L1, L2 are points defining the line, P[i] is i-th polygon vertex
```

Algorithm works in linear time O(N) where N is polygon vertex count. Note that for convex polygons result might be deduced in O(logN) time using binary search.